How to compare a list of data to a specific node in XSLT
Here's what the data looks like:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>   
    <data>
     <country>USA</country>
   </data>
   <data>
     <country>JPN</country>
   </data>
   <data>
     <country>CAN</country>
   </data>
   <data>
     <country>AUS</country>
   </data>
 </root>

I have a list of data stored in a variable delimited by comma:
<xsl:varibale name="inCountry">USA,CAN,AUS</xsl:variable>

I need to get compare the root/data/country from variable inCountry to make sure it's part of the list.
The output should be:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <data>
    <country>USA</country>
  </data>
  <data>
    <country>CAN</country>
  </data>
  <data>
    <country>AUS</country>
  </data>
</root>


/root/data/country[. = tokenize($inCountry, ',')] should do to identify the elements you want to copy. Of course, as the variable value seems to part of the XSLT code, you could consider changing it to <xsl:variable name="inCountry" as="xs:string*" select="'USA', 'CAN', 'AUS'"/> and then test /root/data/country[. = $inCountry].

While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) Well-formed input XML with all relevant namespaces.
(2) Your logic, and complete executable XSLT stylesheet that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.

Please try the following solution.
Input XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <data>
        <country>USA</country>
    </data>
    <data>
        <country>JPN</country>
    </data>
    <data>
        <country>CAN</country>
    </data>
    <data>
        <country>AUS</country>
    </data>
</root>

XSLT 3.0
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" expand-text="yes"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:variable name="inCountry">USA,CAN,AUS</xsl:variable>

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

    <xsl:template match="data">
        <xsl:if test="country = tokenize($inCountry,',')">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Output
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<root>
  <data>
    <country>USA</country>
  </data>
  <data>
    <country>CAN</country>
  </data>
  <data>
    <country>AUS</country>
  </data>
</root>


I currently have same logic using tokenize however when processing mass data, I get a duplicates records

Please see my comments under your original question.

@Paprika, you say you "get a duplicates records", but your question is not about eliminating duplicates (if they are in the input XML), it is only about only processing those elements from the input that have a certain country value in a sequence or list of values.

I would block copying of the elements where the country is not found:
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all">

  <xsl:variable name="inCountry">USA,CAN,AUS</xsl:variable>
  
  <xsl:variable name="in-country-sequence" as="xs:string*" select="tokenize($inCountry, ',')"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="root/data[not(country = $in-country-sequence)]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>

